# Switch Case for dynamic amount of values

Tags: c#, gridview, foreach, switch-statement, case

So this is my [Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6jQd.png)

You can add as much rows as you want to this gridview and when you press the 'Ready' button the program watches your input via the KeyDown-Event.
When you press one of those Hotkeys shown in the gridview you get all the songs which are in the matching path.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
switch (e.KeyValue.ToString().Substring(0, 0))    
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow  item in grdView)
    {
        case item.Cells[2].Value:
        //Get all the songs
        break;
    }        
}
```

Unfortunatelly I get tons of errors. I guess it won't work like this.
Is there any other way to ask for all Hotkeys written in the gridview?

Thanks for any kind of advice.

Comment: Please study the [switch syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) first, you can put a for each loop outside of `switch` or inside the `switch - case`, but not overlap them like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in grdView)
{
    if(item.Cells[2].Value == theValueYouAreLookingFor)
    {
        // Do something here
        break;
    }
}
```

And also e.KeyValue.ToString().Substring(0, 0) doesn't look right,  I'm pretty sure that it isn't going to do quite what you want it to do.

Comment: Oh damn well that was easy. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Although iterating through all items with foreach and checking for equals would work,

I thought its worth to mention few alternative in case someone finds it in the future:

one is `Linq`:

```
var itemFound = grdView.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Cells[2].Value == theValueYouAreLookingFor);
if (itemFound == null)
{
    //no items found in this case
}
```

the other is `Dictionary` which is a more efficient solution to map dynamic amount of options in general, but it you'll have to build it beforehand:

simple build example (do this when the grid is created/changed):

```
shortcutsMap = grdView.ToDictionary(item => item.Cells[2].Value, item);
```

get:

```
var itemFound = shortcutsMap[theValueYouAreLookingFor] //will throw exception if not found
```

or:

```
shortcutsMap.TryGetValue(theValueYouAreLookingFor, out var itemFound) //returns true/false if found and result will be at itemFound
```